# Logstash Grok Filter Spit and put in seperate buckets in Elastic Index

Tags: java, logstash, grok, logstash-grok

Hi I have a log line say like`"APPLE" AND "BANANA" AND "MANGO" OR "GRAPES"`

I want it to mutate like and split to put in elastic , so elastic should have a equivalent as

```
options{
    fruits :{
        'APPLE','BANANA','MANGO','GRAPES'
    },
    operators{
        'AND' ,'AND','OR'
    }
}
```

Is it possible to apply split and put under separate buckets as fruits and operators.

Comment: In real scenario 

Grok = 
`%{WORD:LEVEL}%{SPACE}\[%{GREEDYDATA:ts}\]%{SPACE}\<%{NUMBER:threadNo}\>%{SPACE}\<%{IP:ip}\,%{GREEDYDATA:UID}\,%{GREEDYDATA:user}\,%{NUMBER:num_1}\,%{NUMBER:num_2}\,%{GREEDYDATA:msg1}\,%{GREEDYDATA:msg2}\,\(\(fruits\:\(%{GREEDYDATA:fruits}\)\)\)\,%{NUMBER:num_3}\,%{NUMBER:num_4}\>`
 Sample Log Line 
`STATUS   [06/23 01:00:06.629] <45> <10.51.4.5,0e5a963a-2983-4e4b-98a5-839a0c4d826f_<Identifier>,USER1,45,0,,,((fruits:("apple" AND "GUAVA"))),1,2> `

and in conf if I add a mutate on fruits 
 `mutate {  split => [ "fruits", " " ] }`

Comment: In Elastic for above I get
In elastic I get 
`"fruits": [
    ""apple""
    ,
    "AND"
    ,
    ""banana""

]`

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is "quoted string followed by unquoted string, repeating", I would drop into a ruby{} filter, split on space, examine each word to determine if it's quoted or not, and process as needed.

If not, please expand on your question.